# Printf failing to print array of characters

Tags: c, cs50

My printf() function is continuously printing nothing to the terminal instead of the characters in the array that it is supposed to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[4];
    s[0] = '0';
    s[1] = '0';
    s[2] = '0';
    s[3] = '\0';
    int nums[3] = {0, 0, 0};

    for (int i = 92; i < 110; i++)
    {
        // Number maxes at three digits
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            nums[2 - j] = i % 10;
            i /= 10;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < 3;  k++)
        {
            s[k] = (char) nums[k];
        }

        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the program to print out 3 number increasing every time the loop is completed. If the number is not 3 digits all of the not occupied spots should be 0's.

Comment: I strongly suspect you want `s[k] = nums[k] + '0';`

Comment: And you also shouldn't be modifying `i` inside the loop, that messes with the `i < 110` condition - copy the value to another variable

Answer (score 0):

I was testing out your code as others were commenting on your code.  As I found testing, the program did not print out anything and can running in an endless loop as a result of the issues noted in the comments.  With those comments in mind, following is a refactored version of your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[4];
    s[0] = '0';
    s[1] = '0';
    s[2] = '0';
    s[3] = '\0';
    int nums[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    int x;

    for (int i = 92; i < 110; i++)
    {
        x = i;                          /* Need to use a work variable - shouldn't be modifying the loop counter */
        // Number maxes at three digits
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            nums[2 - j] = x % 10;
            x /= 10;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < 3;  k++)
        {
            s[k] = (char) nums[k] + '0';    /* As noted in the comments */
        }

        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

Things to point out.

- As noted, it is not a good idea to be modifying a variable used as a loop counter within a loop as noted in the endless loop behavior experienced, so the loop counter is placed into a work variable for use on the needed calculations.
- As also noted in the comments, since an ASCII character value is wanted in the character array, the value of character "0" (zero) would need to be added to the integer value derived for each position in order to attain the equivalent character in the character array.

With those bits refactored, following is the terminal output from a test run.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/PrintChars/bin/Release$ ./PrintChars 
092
093
094
095
096
097
098
099
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
```

Give those tweaks a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Thank you, this code works when implemented into the larger project. Can you explain why adding the "0" would change the value nums[k] though? I thought that since I was passing the int into char datatype it would automatically change to the correct ASCII value.

Comment: No.  ASCII conversion does not occur when casting from one data type to another.  You might want to check out this reference for a bit more explanation on casting from one data type to another [C typecasting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-typecasting/).

Comment: See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) What does adding `'0'` to a single digit integer give you? (hint `0 + '0'` is `'0'`, `1 + '0'` is `'1'`, and so on...